# Why isn't there a verb following can?

Tags: grammaticality

I have read a sentence in America Scientist (May 2014, p45):

> No longer can skeptical clinicians dismiss the approach as likely to be viable for only a few specific kinds of tumors...

Why isn't there a verb following can?

Comment: Maochang, there is a verb after can: "dismiss." Rewriting the sentence: "Skeptical clinicians can (no longer) dismiss the approach...". Have you visited our sister site, [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)? It is good for basic questions such as this one. Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear in what sense you mean "following". If you mean immediately after, why should there be? Many ways *can* a sentence be arranged so that a word other than a verb follows.

Comment: *Can Mary stay home?* Q:Why isn't there a verb following *can*? Ans: Yes, there is a verb following *can* - *stay* !!!

Answer (score 1):

The verb associated with *can* in this sentence is *dismiss.*